# Capped at 175 Rep?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I have been making a determined effort to get the reputation cap daily and thus far have achieved the 200 cap 3 days in a row. I have just looked at my reputation today (day 4) and see it's been capped out at 175 - I noticed this as I got 2x upvotes which gave me 11 rep. Is there any reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually already at 200 for today - according to [Mr. Skeet's Reputation Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=103385&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today&showflair=true).

Comment: Thats odd then, my stack profile states 175. Is it to do with timing then perhaps?

Comment: It could be a timing issue - maybe depends when those downvotes come in. How the rep cap behaves wrt downvotes and accepts has always mystified me.

Comment: @Kyle did you click the "today" tab? The default view doesn't display that day's details ("day" in terms of midnight - midnight UTC).

Comment: @Pekka, yea I did, still says 175.

Comment: @Kyle: My rep tracker and the profile tab should agree; have a look at *where* they disagree in the details, if they're disagreeing about the total.

Comment: Seems to have updated now. Its now sitting at 200. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Did someone unaccept an answer of yours? That'd be -15.

Comment: Not that I've seen. I don't think I deleted any upvoted answers either. I do see however that someone un-upvoted one of my answers taking away yesterdays daily cap. That made me a tad sad :P

Comment: Once you hit the cap, if you dip back under it for an unaccept, you're still considered capped?

Comment: @DN, yes, you are capped for the rest of the day, even if you lose 200 rep

Comment: @kyle, you don't see if someone unaccepts, or un-votes you, it's like it never happened!